# How to add selectionMode="multiple" behavior to TreeTable

Tags: primereact

In a DataTable you can add a checkbox column via

https://primereact.org/datatable/#checkbox_row_selection

```
<Column selectionMode="multiple">
```

But this does not seem to work for a TreeTable with selectionMode="checkbox"

https://primereact.org/treetable/#checkbox_row_selection

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
<Column field="nodes" 
        header={<HeaderCheckbox checked={false} onChange={onToggleAll} />} 
        expander 
        style={{ width: "150px", textAlign: "center" }} />
```

```
const HeaderCheckbox = (props: any) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(props.checked);

  return <Checkbox
    checked={checked}
    onChange={e => {
      setChecked(e.checked);
      props.onChange(e.checked);
    }} />
}

const onToggleAll = (checked: boolean) => {
    let selectedNodesKeys = {};
    treeNodes?.forEach((node) => {
      propagateDown(node, checked, selectedNodesKeys);
    });
    setSelectedNodesKeys(selectedNodesKeys);
  }

  const propagateDown = (node: any, check: boolean, selectionKeys: any) => {
    if (check) {
      selectionKeys[node.key] = { checked: true, partialChecked: false };
    }
    else {
      delete selectionKeys[node.key];
    }

    if (node.children && node.children.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        propagateDown(node.children[i], check, selectionKeys);
      }
    }
  };
```